# Word that covers Manga, Comic book, Graphic Novel and Bande dessinée

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that cover all these terms:

- Manga
- Comic book
- Graphic Novel
- Bande dessinée

---

Edit:
Got a few interesting answers:

- Comics (*I was expecting that one*)
- Graphic narrative
- Sequential art

I was also expecting the ninth art.

Comment: "Bande dessinée" isn't used in English, in my experience. I guess that's a ***cartoon strip*** (three or four frames in a self-contained episode, like *Dilbert*).

Comment: I presume all of the above are various forms of **Entertainment**... I can't think of a single word... Perhaps, you could post this to Anime & Manga SE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider, ***comics***.

> *Common forms of comics include comic strips, editorial and gag
> cartoons, and comic books. Since the late 20th century, bound volumes
> such as graphic novels, comics albums, and tankōbon have become
> increasingly common, and online webcomics have proliferated in the
> 21st century.*
>
> *The English term comics derives from the humorous (or comic) work which predominated in early American newspaper comic strips; the term has become standard also for non-humorous works. It is common in English to refer to the comics of different cultures by the terms used in their original languages, such as manga for Japanese comics, or bandes dessinées for French-language comics. There is no consensus amongst theorists and historians on a definition of comics; some emphasize the combination of images and text, some sequentiality or other image relations, and others historical aspects such as mass reproduction or the use of recurring characters. The increasing cross-pollination of concepts from different comics cultures and eras has further made definition difficult* [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comics)

Answer (score 4):

The problem in selecting an appropriate generic word for this type of literature is its variety across international boundaries, with different terms in different languages describing different forms.  You might consider the terminology of *[From Comic Strips to Graphic Novels: Contributions to the Theory and History of Graphic Narrative](https://books.google.com/books?id=3RisCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7&dq=Manga,%20Comic%20book,%20Graphic%20Novel%20and%20Bande%20dessin%C3%A9e&source=bl&ots=46wZiGwsCF&sig=f1OFa0i7J4rf2QdfHhDX03jFV2s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKsPiZz_HJAhUFFT4KHdz9CJY4ChDoAQgbMAA#v=onepage&q=Manga%2C%20Comic%20book%2C%20Graphic%20Novel%20and%20Bande%20dessin%C3%A9e&f=false)*, in which the editors Daniel Stein and Jan-Noël Tho say that they subscribe "to the more general notion of '**graphic narrative**,'" while considering the "varieties of graphic storytelling"

> from different American comics formats to Francophone *bande
>   dessinée*, Italian *fumetti*, German *Bildergeschichten* or *grafishe
>   Literatur*, Asian *magna*, *manhua*, or *manhwa*, and the whole
>   panoply of globally dispersed types of **graphic narratives** routinely
>   discussed in the pages of John A. Lent's *International Journal of
>   Comic Art* (1999-).

Answer (score 1):

The term that has gained most traction for these forms as a group, while leaving space for their formal differences from each other, is **sequential art**.

This captures the ***visual*** nature of all the forms mentioned in the OP’s question, along with the creation of ***narrative*** in each case, with or without a linguistic component (e.g. speech bubbles).

In the process, the term also gently distinguishes these forms from single graphics and from moving-image artforms.  There will always be corner cases of overlap or exception, but ‘sequential art’ is now sufficiently established and conventional for these groupings and distinctions to be generally understood for purposes of discussion.

This term appears to have been coined by the great comics artist Will Eisner.  It has been powerfully taken-up by people like Scott McCloud (both practitioner and scholar), for example in his splendid book *Understanding Comics*, which rather magnificently makes its points by presenting itself in comics format.

[A sampler of *Understanding Comics* is available online from the publisher](http://www.harpercollins.com/web-sampler/9780060976255) (and McCloud’s analytical acknowledgment of Eisner is on p5).